# Linker error in Visual Studio 2017 (unresolved external symbol)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, header, linker

I use Visual Studio 2017 RC. I added all these files to my solution:

---

---

main.cpp

```
#include "B.h"
#include "AAA.h"
int main()
{
    AAA gen;
    gen.Create();
    return 0;
}
```

AAA.h

```
#ifndef _H_AAA
#define _H_AAA
class AAA
{
public:
    void Function();
};
#endif // _H_AAA
```

AAA.cpp

```
#include "AAA.h"
#include "B.h"
void AAA::Function()
{
    B obj;
    obj.Function();
}
```

B.h

```
#ifndef _H_B
#define _H_B
class B
{
public:
    void Function();
};
#endif // _H_B
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"
void B::Function()
{}
```

---

---

When I try to compile it, VS shows that error:

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public:  
  void __thiscall B::Function(void)" (?Function@B@@QAEXXZ)  
  referenced in function "public:  
  void __thiscall AAA::Function(void)" (?Function@AAA@@QAEXXZ)`
```

If I use gcc, it doesn't show any errors.
Why is this happening and how to fix that problem?

@EDIT

I created new project and copied there all these files. It works fine now, but I still don't understand this strange behavior of VS.

Comment: "_It works fine now_" So, is the problem sorted now? Does your code work?

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer Yes, but I don't know why the code in the first project doesn't work and the same code in new project works well. I didn't change any preferences of these ones.

Comment: You dont happen to have the original vcxproj file, do you? Or the build logs? You say you added them to the project - how did you do so? I feel like the B.cpp files may have been added as a header, in which case the compiler would not have generated an object, and the linker would fail. I think the msbuild should be <clcompile>B.cpp</clcompile> and your probably was <clinclude>B.cpp </clinclude>

Comment: @KevinK You're right. B.cpp was added as header, so when I change vcxproj file like you said, everything works ok. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

Right click on project > Add > Reference

Then add your library project as reference.